# Can't install django-haystack

Tags: django

I am trying to install django-haystack for solr-jetty. All seems to work but I have two problems that are probably unrelated:

a) When I "import haystack" from within python I get the message belllow:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD,   settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

b) When trying to set up solr and I do sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start, I get:

- Starting Jetty servletengine.jetty                                         start-stop-daemon: user 'solr' not found
- (already running).

I am having trouble figuring out where the problems are coming from. Can anyone help out?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got it. For a) I have to do export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=nirla.settings.   b) is still a question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its looking for a user named 'solr' on the system.

You can add the user using: `sudo adduser solr`

Comment: Yes. useradd -d /opt/solr -s /sbin/false solr  did the job for me.